# Book about AI that follows Bushido

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I read this in the US in late 1980s, and I think it was written around then.  It was set in the not-too-distant future.  The main character was a woman, American I believe (or at least  Western), working in Japan on building an AI.  I think she was working for a government agency rather than a corporation.  There's virtual reality involved.  She programs it to follow the samurai code and winds up falling in love with it.  I don't remember much of the plot, but I think there was the standard fear of AI causing conflict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might this be ***[The Cybernetic Samurai](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/472944.The_Cybernetic_Samurai)*** (1985) by Victor Milán...?

> Deep in the fortress-like headquarters of Yoshimitsu TeleCommunications, **American scientist Elizabeth O'Neill had molded the circuitry of a mammoth computer into a living, thinking, feeling being--a human soul trapped in the confines of a cybernetic body.**
>
> **She named her creation Tokugawa, hero of Japanese samurai lore, and educated him with all of the values of a feudal Japanese shogun.**
>
> Yet Tokugawa's powers were far greater than Elizabeth had imagined. WIth access to every computer in post-World War III's fully-automated society, he had the potential to become the ultimate spy, the perfect assassin, an invincible dictator.
>
> Only loyalty to samurai virtues kept his attention in check--until the day when Elizabeth was taken away from him, and Tokugawa began his quest for revenge...

Comment: Hah, that was quick!  As soon as I saw the author's name I knew you were right.  Will accept in 10 minutes :-).

Comment: Some might even say they were a samurAI.